# Get file back inside project directory in Xcode project

Tags: xcode, git

I created a new iOS application in Xcode. I then created a new view controller, but it created the file at the root of my project, so in Xcode I just dragged the file into the folder named after my application.

After committing and pushing to my remote Git repository, I noticed that the view controller file I created (`EventListViewController.swift`) is in the *root* of my repository, where the ***.xcodeproj** directory is.

How can I get my Swift file back in the project directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually just move the file to the appropriate folder in Finder and then delete the file's reference in Xcode and re-add it. Xcode's file structure in the project navigator does not match what is on disk. When you move files around there it does not change their location on disk. This is being changed in Xcode 9.

The other way is to change the location in the Utilities pane under Identity and Type:

[image: File Location Screenshot]

Comment: Yeah, I didn’t want to move it using Git as I thought I’d mess up references. Can I not “move” the file, or will I have to remove the reference and re-add?

Comment: I've updated with another solution. It is possible to change the reference of the file in the Utilities try on the right side of Xcode.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you!